# 'middleware' => 'auth'. I cant access my dashboard

Tags: laravel-5

It was successfuly protected, it will redirect back to the login page when the user try to type /dasboard to the URL. but the problem is, I cant access my dashboard even I input the correct email and password..

this my userController.php file

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class userController extends Controller
{   
    public function getDashBoard()
    {
       return view('dashboard');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'email'=> 'required',
                'password'=> 'required'
            ]);

        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request['email'], 'password'=>  $request['password']])){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

this my routes.php file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('login');
    })->name('home');

    Route::get('/dashboard', [
       'uses'=> 'userController@getDashBoard',
       'as'=> 'dashboard'
       'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
});
```

and this my Authenticate.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
  {
      if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
          if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
              return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
          } else {
            return redirect()->route('home');
          }
      }

      return $next($request);
  } 
}
```

I need help. I'am new in this laravel 5.2 framework. better if you edit my code so that I could understand and know my mistake..

Thank you for understanding. Slow learner here..

Answer (score 0):

According to the code provided there doesn't seem to be a getDashBoard method within your UserController. Your 'dashboard' route is pointing to a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry I have my dashboard. Its my mistake for not including it here. Wait I will paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but when I turn off the machine to take a sleep. And then turn on the machine again. When I run my application it was suddenly fix.. hmmmm...